# Match and save one or more occurrences within a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string with one or more times within in hh:mm:ss format. I created this regex to try and save the times with grouping so I then could do some work:

```
if ( $s =~ /(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)/ )
{
  my @t = ( $2, $5, $8 );
  # loop through times and do stuff
}
else
{
  # no match found
}
```

The problem is that the string may have one, two, or three embedded times - and this regex seems to work only when all three are present (not for one or two). Is there a better way to do this (and to avoid any "Use of uninitialized value" warnings!)?

I tried this, but then it only grabs the last time:

```
/(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?(.*)/
```

Comment: Why the (.*)... if you do not want to capture, you could use a non-capturing group (?:.*) or, even better, just .*

Comment: In addition, altho it will not solve your problem, you should be using .*? to make that non-greedy

Comment: `\d` matches about 100 different characters. You might want `[0-9]` instead or use `/a`.

Answer (score 8):

Match [`g`lobally](http://p3rl.org/op#%2fPATTERN%2fmsixpodualgc) to repeat a pattern. Avoid backref variables if all you are going to do with them is to assign them immediately to some better named variable; the match operator already returns the capture buffer results.

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $timestamp = qr'
    (?<!\d)            # avoid digits before
    \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}  # hh:mm:ss
    (?!\d)             # avoid digits after
'x;

for my $s (qw(
    foo18:00:00bar18:00:00baz18:00:00quux
    foo18:00:00bar18:00:00baz
    foo18:00:00bar
)) {
    if (my @t = $s =~ /($timestamp)/g) {
        print Dumper \@t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you might want to add some lookbehind/lookahead conditions to weed out false positives.  e.g. `(?<!\d)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\d)` so it won't match 1234:56:7890.

Comment: This is much cleaner than how I was going about it, thanks, my only question is once I manipulate the times, how do I update the original string $s with the new times $t[0..$#t] ? Is there any way to back reference the hh:mm:ss match from the regex using grouping ?

Comment: [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide sample data and the code for manipulating the times.